# How to replace/update dictionary in Array of Dictionary based on Type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I'm getting below JSON response from server, and displaying phone number on screen.

Now user can change/update any of phone number, so we have to update particular mobile number in same object and send it to server.

```
"phone_numbers": [
                {
                    "type": "MOBILE",
                    "number": "8091212121"
                },
                {
                    "type": "HOME",
                    "number": "4161212943"
                },
                {
                    "type": "BUSINESS",
                    "number": "8091212344"
                }
            ]
```

My model class is looks like this:

```
public struct Contact: Decodable {
    public let phone_numbers: [Phone]?
}

public struct Phone: Decodable {
    public let type: PhoneType?
    public let number: String?
}
```

I'm struggling to update this JSON object for particular phone number.

For example, if I want to update BUSINESS number only in above array, What's best way to do it.
I'm using XCode 11 and Swift 5.

Comment: isnt type a String ? Why you declared it as PhoneType ? Where are you stuck ? Please show what you tried.

Comment: No. it's not string, it's enum with all expected types of phone number from server.
Based on that `Type` we identify which number to update. Also backend use similar logic to identify.

Comment: I'm stuck at updating this dictionary. As already explained, for example, If user inputs new mobile number for type BUSINESS, how can I find that object in array and replace existing number?

Comment: where do you want to update the number ? In the array you stored this json ?

Comment: obviously yes, where else can I save? You can see it in my model class.
I saved it in Array of Dictionary.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of details that would help us in answering, so what's obvious to you may not be to the people who are trying to help you. I've tried to read between the lines and guess at what your problem might be, but I really don't know if my answer addresses your problem or if you're stuck on something else entirely. For best results, don't just say "I'm struggling," but instead show us some piece of code that fails to do what you think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all your properties are defined as constants (`let`), nothing can be updated. You have to initialize and return a new `Contact` object with the updated phone numbers.

If you change the properties to `var`, then you can update:

```
public enum PhoneType: String, Decodable {
    case mobile = "MOBILE"
    case home = "HOME"
    case business = "BUSINESS"
}

public struct Contact: Decodable {
    public var phone_numbers: [Phone]?

    mutating func update(phoneNumber: String, for type: PhoneType) {
        guard let phone_numbers = self.phone_numbers else { return }

        for (i, number) in phone_numbers.enumerated() {
            if number.type ==  type {
                self.phone_numbers![i].number = phoneNumber
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct Phone: Decodable {
    public var type: PhoneType?
    public var number: String?
}

var contact = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Contact.self, from: jsonData)
contact.update(phoneNumber: "123456", for: .business)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to approach this (I'm assuming PhoneType is an enum you have somewhere)

You can iterate over the array and guard for only business numbers, like so

```
for phone in phone_numbers{
    guard phone.type == .MOBILE else { continue }
    // Code that modifies phone
}
```

You can filter and iterate over the array, like so

```
phone_numbers.filter {$0.type == .BUSINESS }.forEach { phone in
// Modify phone here
}
```

You can then modify the right value in the array with it's index, like this

```
for (phoneIndex, phone) in phone_numbers.enumerated() {
    guard phone.type == .BUSINESS else { continue }
    phone_numbers[phoneIndex].type = ANOTHER_TYPE
}
```

Some can argue that the second is preferred over the first, because it is an higher order function, but in my day to day activities, I tend to use both and believe that this is a matter of taste

Comment: I already did this part. My exact question was What to do after this this?
Because your code is filtering out the object to update. but now how to update `phone_numbers` object?

Comment: You can try `phone.type = ANOTHER_TYPE`. If that does't work, you need to modify the array itself, so it would be `phone_numbers[PHONE_INDEX].type = ANOTHER_TYPE`.
I'll edit the answer to include the iteration with the array modification

Answer (score 1):

> I'm struggling to update this JSON object for particular phone number.

It shouldn't be a JSON object when you update it. Think of JSON as just a format for transferring data. Once transferred, you should parse it into something that you can work with, like an array of dictionaries or whatever. If you've done that, then more specific questions you might ask are:

- How can I find a specific entry in an array?
- How can I modify the fields of a struct?
- How can I replace one entry in an array with another?

After looking at the definitions of your structures, I think the problem you're having probably has to do with how you've declared them:

```
public struct Phone: Decodable {
    public let type: PhoneType?
    public let number: String?
}
```

Because you used `let` to declare `type` and `number`, those fields *cannot be changed* after initialization. If you want the fields of a `Phone` struct to be modifiable, you need to declare them with `var` instead of `let`.

The same thing is true for your `Contact` struct:

```
public struct Contact: Decodable {
    public let phone_numbers: [Phone]?
}
```

You've declared `phone_numbers` as an *immutable* array because you used `let` instead of `var`. If you want to be able to add, remove, or modify the array in `phone_numbers`, you need to use `var` instead.

The struct declarations you have right now work fine for reading the data from JSON because all the components of the JSON data are constructed using the values from the JSON. But again, you'll need to make those structs modifiable by switching to `var` declarations if you want to be able to make changes.